# How do I check a file exists or not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I check a file exists or not in Javascript?

I know a way which is through XMLHTTP component and checking ".status"  will tell is it exists or not.

Is there any other preferred way?

Thanks.

**EDIT** The file will be on server.

Comment: Where the file is supposed to exist? On the server-side or client-side?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention at first. It will be on server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since JavaScript running in the browser does not have direct access to the file system, there is no way.

Nice article with some options that you have - [Reading a file from local file system using Javascript](http://dev-technomind.blogspot.com/2008/05/reading-file-using-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

there are no way to check filesystem on client via javascript. It's because of security.

I think, you can try to upload file to the server and get answer from server-side, if AJAX-technology allows to upload files.

But I hope, no. Or else you can upload all my system and security files, if I visit your site :)